# Is there a way in a Linux os to create a reference to file which is not dependent on it's location or name?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Let's say I have a file which needs to be referenced by other files and it needs to be possible to move and rename this file without breaking the reference in all the other files. Is there a way to achieve that? It's a linux-like os question but if someone had an answer for windows, I will appreciate it too.

I came up with an idea involving symlinks. I created a simple python script which first finds all links pointing to a file being moved (using mlocate), moves the file and then updates all the links. All the other files that need a reference to this file reference it by a symlink. It works, but it means I need a symlink for every file I want to reference and I need to store them somewhere. It's not even that bad but I want to know if there exists a better way. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: It depends on your needs, but one option is to use hard links for this, not symbolic links.  There's no "master" in that case; all the filenames just point to the same inode.  You just have to be a little careful if you have to update the file; if you have an editor that copies to a new name and renames the files into place, that can break the hard link.

Comment: When I used to have to mess with this sort of thing, hard links only worked  on the same local file system, and if I wanted a link to something that was nfs mounted (for instance), I had to use sim-links. I don't think that has changed, but that was Sun, 20 yrs ago (-;! Good luck to all.

Comment: How does your symlink solution work if someone renames the file without using your script that fixes the symlink?

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than your symlink solution. Files can be identified uniquely using a filesystem ID and inode number, but there's no way to access the file using this. To access the file you need its name.

Comment: Also, file system IDs are not permanently assigned to NFS mounts.

Comment: @TimRoberts Right, I forgot about a hardlinks. They let me create a reference to file which does not break with file move or rename. I can reference the hardlink from the other programs then but what if I wanted to move a hardlink. Is there no other way to create reference that works independently from file name or location?

Comment: Moving a hardlink doesn't have any effect on other hardlinks.

Comment: When you move a file, all that does is create a new file with the same inode.  It essentially creates a new hard link and the erases the old one.  The rest of the hard links are all preserved.  In MY view, the NFS concerns are irrelevant.  I don't think NFS is a significant player any more.

Comment: @Barmar Basically, the next time you launch the program referencing the symlink it will break because the symlink is not valid.

Comment: If all your references are on the same filesystem, the hardlink method will be best.

Comment: Note that this actually depends on how users update the file you're linking to. If they create a new file and then do `mv newfile yourfile`, the hard link will continue to refer to the original file, not the replacement.

Comment: @Barmar All right, I guess. I don't know if you ever used unreal engine blueprints, but i looked for a solution that would work as good as the object referencing there. I can create a class and reference another class from a variable there, then move or rename the referenced class and the value of the variable updates automatically. I know blueprints are pretty high-level but i'm not afraid to get my hands dirty if the cleanest solution involved some coding :).

Comment: The Unix filesystem is not object-oriented. There are no direct references to files as objects. One of the reasons is permissions: to acces a file, you need execute permission to the containing directory. So accesses have to be via pathnames so the parent permissions can be checked.

Comment: @TimRoberts, there's lots of NFS still out there.  But even if you disregard that, hardlinks do not span filesystems, and NFS is not the only filesystem type that does not support them.  Not that that necessarily makes them a bad fit for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two approaches to this:

1. hardlinks. As described in comments, these do what you ask, with the limitations given:

   - hardlinks can easily be broken if you're not careful, and
   - they only work within the same filesystem (which furthermore has to be among those that support it).

   Also, you should not make hardlinks to directories.
2. bind mounts.  You can `mount --bind /path/to/real_file /another/path/other_name` to make `/path/to/real_file` accessible as `/another/path/other_name`.  Important characteristics of this approach include:

   - mounts are not persistent.  They have to be set up anew at each boot, typically with the help of `/etc/fstab` or some other kind of configuration
   - `mount`ing is a privileged action.  Ordinary users can't do it.
   - unlike hardlinks, bind mounts *can* span filesystems.
   - there has to be an actual file (which can be empty) to mount on.
   - renaming, deleting, and similar filesystem operations will need to be done differently